# Understanding `tru` in Lambda Calculus from TAPL

Tags: lambda-calculus

In Dr. Benjamin Pierce's Types and Programming Languages, page 58 notes:

> Another language feature than can be easily encoded in the lambda-calculus is boolean values and conditions. Define the terms `tru` and `fals` as follows:

tru  = $\lambda$t. $\lambda$f. t;

fals = $\lambda$t. $\lambda$f.  f;

> The terms `tru` and `fls` can be viewed as *representing* the boolean values "true" and "false," in the sense that we can use these terms to perform the operation of testing the truth of a boolean value.

Looking at the `tru` definition (if that's the right word), what does each term mean? I assume that `t` is the argument to the function?

In short, I'm requesting an explanation of the terms of `tru`. In addition, I'd appreciate an explanation of how `tru` would be called/invoked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of `tru` as a function of two arguments (represented by currying): it takes args `(t, f)` to `t`. These are not great name choices, since they're easily confused with "true" and "false"; I could equally well have said "it takes args `(x, y)` to `x`," instead. But you'll see shortly why they're used.

Similarly, `fals` takes `(t, f)` to `f`.

Why these are the right definitions? That's a little trickier.

Suppose you have an expression like

`if cond then e1 else e2`

whose value is `e1` if the condition is true, and whose value is `e2` if the condition is false. You can rewrite this in lambda-calc form as

`cond(e1, e2)`

(or, in real lambda calc form, as "cond e1 e2", since it eschews parens...but I find programming-language-like form easier to read).

If `cond` is `tru`, then `cond(e1, e2)` will be `e1`; if it's `fals`, then `cond(e1, e2)` will be `e2`, just as desired.

So an "if expression" can be encoded as a function-application, where the applied function is the "condition", which is either "tru" or "false".

I apologize for this answer using kind of a mashup of notations, etc., but I hope that the gist comes across OK.

Comment: Reading your answer, it made me think of `(const True) :: b -> Bool` in Haskell. So, `tru` can be expressed in Haskell as: `tru = const True`, no?

Comment: Also, as a follow-up, the lambda's in `tru` are simply arguments? And `t` is the output representing the `True` Boolean, i.e. a constant?

Comment: @KevinMeredith true and false are defined so that the construction "if B then X else Y" is represented in lambda-calculus by "B X Y". If B is true then it will reduce to X, and if B is false then it will reduce to Y.

Comment: I know nothing about Haskell. It does not appear to me that the Haskell thing you've written corresponds to the lambda-calc notion I've described, but maybe it's just my lack of knowledge of the language.

Answer (score 0):

You could view `tru` as the map $(t,f) \mapsto t$ and `fals` as the map $(t,f) \mapsto f$. In a different choice of words, `tru` is the projection on the first factor of a Cartesian product of two objects, while `fals` is the projection on the second one. They are precisely the functions `car` and `cdr` from Scheme. That these two functions may be used to simulate boolean operations is, indeed, amazing.